# Leaflet side by side plugin is not working with imageOverlay

Tags: leaflet, javascript, overlay, leaflet-plugins

I'm trying to use the [side by side](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side) plugin. I already check in the issues and change the `getContainter()` with `getPane()` in the .js file.

```
this._divider.style.left = dividerX + 'px'
    this.fire('dividermove', {x: dividerX})
    var clipLeft = 'rect(' + [nw.y, clipX, se.y, nw.x].join('px,') + 'px)'
    var clipRight = 'rect(' + [nw.y, se.x, se.y, clipX].join('px,') + 'px)'
    if (this._leftLayer) {
      this._leftLayer.getPane().style.clip = clipLeft
    }
    if (this._rightLayer) {
      this._rightLayer.getPane().style.clip = clipRight
    }
  },
```

I'm using `imageOverlay` but i don't know where to add the `map.createPane('left');map.createPane('right');` that is mentioned in [the issue](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side/issues/4#issuecomment-285058096).

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [23.140, -101.887],
    zoom: 5
});

var catedralVieja = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[7.9409, -131.1589], [29.2144, -82.6558]];
L.imageOverlay(catedralVieja, imageBounds, {opacity:0.7, pane:"left"}).addTo(map);

var catedralNueva = 'https://img.vixdata.io/pd/jpg-large/es/sites/default/files/a/atlantis-ciudad-perdida.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[7.9409, -131.1589], [29.2144, -82.6558]];
L.imageOverlay(catedralNueva, imageBounds, {opacity: 0.7, pane:"right"}).addTo(map);

var hash = new L.Hash(map);

L.control.sideBySide(catedralVieja, catedralNueva).addTo(map);
```

[This is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djxf9cu7/) that i have and not even the divider appears :(

Comment: Please include your JS code in the body of question, don't give just link.

Comment: @TomazicM done :)

Answer (score 3):

As you stated correctly, you first have to modify `leaflet-side-by-side` plugin by replacing every occurence of `getContainter()` method with `getPane()` method.

Then you have to create two map panes (for example named `'left'` and `'right'`) and use them when creating image overlays.

And when adding control `L.control.sideBySide` to the map, you have to use image layers, not image urls as you did.

Code should look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [23.140, -101.887],
  zoom: 5
});

map.createPane('left');
map.createPane('right');

var catedralVieja = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
imageBounds = [[7.9409, -131.1589], [29.2144, -82.6558]];
var leftLayer = L.imageOverlay(catedralVieja, imageBounds, {pane: 'left'}).addTo(map);

var catedralNueva = 'https://img.vixdata.io/pd/jpg-large/es/sites/default/files/a/atlantis-ciudad-perdida.jpg',
imageBounds = [[7.9409, -131.1589], [29.2144, -82.6558]];
var rightLayer = L.imageOverlay(catedralNueva, imageBounds, {pane: 'right'}).addTo(map);
     

L.control.sideBySide(leftLayer, rightLayer).addTo(map);
```

**EDIT**: The above solution does not work in Leaflet v1.9. For solution see answer to this question: [imageOverlay is not working with Leaflet side-by-side](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451897/imageoverlay-is-not-working-with-leaflet-side-by-side/452123#452123)

Comment: Great solution - Thanks!