# Leaflet: Compare two side-by-side GeoJSON layers?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, legend, popup, leaflet-plugins

I'm trying to use the side-by-side plugin downloaded from https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side. I want to create side-by-side GeoJSON layers to compare the cancer rates between the two years and to show the legend for each layer, but I don't know what am I doing wrong because only one layer is displayed on both sides or they overlap. I guess I should change some of the code in the js file, but I don't know what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Cancer Rates Iowa</title>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui' />
    <script src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.1/leaflet.js'></script>
    <script src="leaflet-side-by-side.js"></script>
    <link href='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.1/leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="Cancer_IA.geojson"></script>
    <style>
         body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }

        #map{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .legend {
            text-align: left;
            line-height: 40px;
            color: #555;
        }
        .legend i {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 8px;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

        var map = L.map('map').setView([42.0667, -93.4], 8);

        var basemap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 19
        }).addTo(map);

        function getColor(d) {
            return d > 545.0 ? '#191710' :
                    d > 497.0  ? '#4c4730' :
                    d > 462.0  ? '#665e40' :
                    d > 406.0  ? '#7f7650' :
                    d > 316.0  ? '#b2a570' :
                                '#e5d590';
        }
        function style(feature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.IA_2000_Ra)
            };
        }

        var osmLayer = L.geoJson(cancer, {
            style: style,

        }).addTo(map);

        var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
        legend.onAdd = function (map) {

            var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                grades = [316.0, 406.0, 462.0, 497.0, 545.0],
                labels = [],
                from, to;

                for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    from = grades[i];
                    to = grades[i + 1];

                    labels.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
            return div;
        };

        legend.addTo(map);

        function getColor1(d) {
            return d > 574 ? '#4D0026' :
                    d > 504.0  ? '#48006a' :
                    d > 446.0  ? '#dd3497' :
                    d > 353.0  ? '#fcc5c0' :
                    d > 308.0  ? '#fef3f2' :
                                '#fff7f3';
        }

        function style1(feature1) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: getColor1(feature1.properties.IA_2016_Ra)
            };
        }

        var stamenLayer = L.geoJson(cancer, {
            style: style1,
        }).addTo(map);

        var legend1 = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});

        legend1.onAdd = function (map) {
            var div1 = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                grades1 = [308.0, 353.0, 446.0, 504.0, 574.0],
                labels1 = [],
                from1, to1;

                for (var i = 0; i < grades1.length; i++) {
                    from = grades1[i];
                    to = grades1[i + 1];

                    labels1.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor1(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

            div1.innerHTML = labels1.join('<br>');
            return div1;
        };
        legend1.addTo(map);


        L.control.sideBySide(stamenLayer, osmLayer).addTo(map);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Solution to this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333229/leaflet-side-by-side-plugin-is-not-working-with-imageoverlay/333346 should also work in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me a lot. Below I pasted the complete code. The Side-by-side plugin now works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
Indicated in [Leaflet side by side plugin is not working with imageOverlay](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333229/leaflet-side-by-side-plugin-is-not-working-with-imageoverlay/333346) I changed getContainer() method with getPane() method. This method returns the HTML element representing the named pane on the map (https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side/issues/4).
Then in the HTML document createPane() method was added to create two map panes named ‘left’ and ‘right’. [image]
Finally, GeoJSON layers were created with L.geoJson() from GeoJSON format data.
With “pane:’left’”, “pane:’right’ option and add.To() layers were then displayed to the created panes: [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <!--A title-->
        <title>Cancer Rates Iowa</title>

        <!-- referencing the leaflet files and county document  -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui' />
        <script src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.1/leaflet.js'></script>
        <script src="leaflet-side-by-side.js"></script>
        <link href='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.1/leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script src="Cancer_IA.geojson"></script>
        <style>
             body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                }

            #map{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .info {
                padding: 6px 8px;
                font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                background: white;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
                box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .legend {
                text-align: left;
                line-height: 40px;
                color: #555;
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: 20px;
                border-radius: 20px;
            }
            .legend i {
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 8px;
                opacity: 0.7;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>

        <script>

            var map = L.map('map').setView([42.0667, -93.4], 8);
            map.createPane('left');
            map.createPane('right');

            var baseMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
                subdomains: 'abcd',
                maxZoom: 19,
                layers: baseMap
            });

            var baseMapIndex = {
                "BaseMap": baseMap
            };

            layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMapIndex).addTo(map);

            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 545.0 ? '#4D0026' :
                        d > 497.0  ? '#48006a' :
                        d > 462.0  ? '#dd3497' :
                        d > 406.0  ? '#fcc5c0' :
                        d > 316.0  ? '#fef3f2' :
                                    '#fff7f3';
            }
            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.IA_2000_Ra)
                };
            }
            function highlightFeature(e) {
                var layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    dashArray: '',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                })

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }
            function resetHighlight(e) {
                overlay1.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,

                })
                layer.bindPopup('<b>County:' + feature.properties.COUNTY + '<br/><br/>'+
                    'Cancer Rate for 2000: </b><br>'
                    + feature.properties.IA_2000_Ra + '<br/><br/>'+
                    'Cancer Rate for 2016: </b><br>'
                    + feature.properties.IA_2000_Ra);
            }

            var overlay1 = L.geoJson(cancer, {
                style: style,
                pane: 'left',
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

            var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [316.0, 406.0, 462.0, 497.0, 545.0],
                    labels = ['<strong> Cancer Rate, 2000 </strong>'],
                    from, to;

                    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                        from = grades[i];
                        to = grades[i + 1];

                        labels.push(
                            '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                            from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                    }

                div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);

            function getColor1(d) {
                return d > 574 ? '#4D0026' :
                        d > 504.0  ? '#48006a' :
                        d > 446.0  ? '#dd3497' :
                        d > 353.0  ? '#fcc5c0' :
                        d > 308.0  ? '#fef3f2' :
                                    '#fff7f3';
            }

            function style1(feature1) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                    fillColor: getColor1(feature1.properties.IA_2016_Ra)
                };
            }
            function highlightFeature1(e) {
                var layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    dashArray: '',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                })

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }
            function resetHighlight1(e) {
                overlay2.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function onEachFeature1(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature1,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight1,

                })
                layer.bindPopup('<b>County:' + feature.properties.COUNTY + '<br/><br/>'+
                    'Cancer Rate for 2016: </b><br>'
                    + feature.properties.IA_2016_Ra + '<br/><br/>'+
                    'Cancer Rate for 2000: </b><br>'
                    + feature.properties.IA_2000_Ra);
            }

            var overlay2 = L.geoJson(cancer, {
                style: style1,
                pane: 'right',
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature1
            }).addTo(map);


            var legend1 = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend1.onAdd = function (map) {
                var div1 = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades1 = [308.0, 353.0, 446.0, 504.0, 574.0],
                    labels1 = ['<strong> Cancer Rate, 2016 </strong>'],
                    from1, to1;

                    for (var i = 0; i < grades1.length; i++) {
                        from = grades1[i];
                        to = grades1[i + 1];

                        labels1.push(
                            '<i style="background:' + getColor1(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                            from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                    }

                div1.innerHTML = labels1.join('<br>');
                return div1;
            };
            legend1.addTo(map);

            L.control.sideBySide(overlay1, overlay2).addTo(map);    
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you found solution, please add some explanation why it didn't work before and how you corrected it. This can then help others with similar problems.